# How to create python classes in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I've tried to created and use classes in jupyter notebook.
But it seems it doesn't work
And I've tried this :

```
def pxlocal(line, cell):
    ip = get_ipython()
    ip.run_cell_magic("px", line, cell)
    ip.run_cell(cell)
ip.register_magic_function(pxlocal, "cell")
```

And in different cell:

`%%pxlocal
class MyClass(object):`

But when I run those two cells it gave me this error:

```
ERROR:root:Cell magic `%%px` not found.
In [11]:
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is `pxlocal` suppose to be doing, and why do you need it to write a class in a notebook?

Answer (score 10):

There is no problem with defining a class in a different cell.
Just make sure you define the class in a cell that appears before the cell that uses it.

Comment: Well, the cells can *appear* in any order, but the cell with the class definition has to *run* before any cells that use that class.

Comment: Does this also work if defining two classes and wanting to use class A in class B?

Answer (score -2):

In Jupyter Notebooks you have to be very areful about usage of cells and positioning.
Like in your case if you want to create any class and then use it. For that you have to specify cell definition in one cell and afterthat only you can use it's functionalties

You can sse this simple example-

```
class Boy():

def _init_(self, name):

    self.name = name
```

And now I use it -

```
boy1 = Boy(name='Jack')
```